# Is there a way to adjust mouse sensitivity?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

Pretty much what it says in the title.  As far as I can tell, there is no menu option for this and the default sensitivity is way too high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it from either Windows, or from the config file found here: `Users\Documents\WB Games\Batman Arkham City\BmGame\Config\bminput.ini`